# peewee: Where does invalid field go when I create()?

Tags: python, peewee

In Peewee, when I create an instance by calling `create()` method with an **invalid** field name, I don't get any error.  Where does it go?  Is it just as it is?

```python
from peewee import *
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict

db = SqliteDatabase('/tmp/a.db')

class User(Model):
    name = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.create_tables([User])

uid = User.create(name="John", foo="bar")
u = User.get_by_id(uid)
print(model_to_dict(u))  #=> {'id': 5, 'name': 'John'}
```

In the above example, I don't have the field `foo` in the class `User`, but the code just ends without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets assigned as an attribute on the object:

```
class Foo(Model):
    pass

f = Foo(a='something', b='another')
print(f.a)  # "something"
print(f.b)  # "another"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see that. 
 https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/3.1.1/peewee.py#L5020